# Sitecore WeBlog Module Issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore-workflow

We are using version 2.2.1 of Sitecore WeBlog module and are experiencing the following intermittent, but frequent, issue when website visitors try to post a Comment on a Blog posting:

On correctly filling in the Name, Email, Comment and Captcha form fields, then clicking the Post button, the form remains completed and displays the message “Processing… please wait for a few seconds”.

After about 30 seconds the message “Processing… please wait for a few seconds” disappears and leaves the completed form displayed; no Comment is added to the Sitecore workflow.

Sometimes the Comment system works fine after about 10 to 15 seconds of displaying the “Processing… please wait for a few seconds” it then clears the form fields and displays a “Thank You” message and the Comment is successfully added into Sitecore workflow.

The web site and dedicated web server is not under heavy load and the rest of the website is very fast when we observe this issue.

We have not experienced this issue on our development version of the website.

1)  Have you seen this issue before and can you suggest how we can resolve it?

2)  For successful Comment posts, we’d be interested in understanding how we can speed up the post process so that the message “Processing… please wait for a few seconds” is displayed only very briefly, if at all, as some visitors are clicking the Post button multiple times whist this is displayed resulting in 2 or 3 identical Comments appearing in the Sitecore workflow.  This successful Comment post process is near instantaneous on our development version of the website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a bug in version 2.2.1 of Sitecore WeBlog module. It worked perfectly when I upgrade it to the next version.